Find the maximum value of $(5+x)^3(5-x)^4$ for all real $x$ less than 5.

Find the maximum value of $(5+x)^3(5-x)^4$ for all real $x$ less than 5.

Is there anyway to find it without calculus with inequalities ?
Couldn't use A.M.-G.M. so thought posting it here .

Ok my bad it's clear we can use am-gm since in the order to maximize the expression $x \in (-5, 5)$

In an AM $\ge$ GM inequality, the equality happens when all items involved is the same. What happens when you apply AM $\ge$ GM to 3 copies of $\frac{5+x}{3}$ and 4 copies of $\frac{5-x}{4}$?

For $x \in (-5, 5)$,we have $(20+4x)^3(15-3x)^4$ as the product of $7$ positive terms with a constant sum, hence this gets maximised (by AM-GM) when all terms are equal, i.e. iff $20+4x=15-3x \iff x = -\frac57$.
Hence the maximum value of $(5+x)^3(5-x)^4$, which is a scaled version of the same product, is when $x=-\frac57$, which gives a maximum of $(5-\frac57)^3\,(5+\frac57)^4$.
